# nginx - Rewrite URL Parameter to Path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

So we ran into an SEO issue with a WPML after changing from using URL parameters to specify the site language to using the path. The web server is running nginx.

**Before:**

> example.com/?lang=fr
>
> example.com/example-path/?lang=fr

**After:**

> example.com/fr/
>
> example.com/fr/example-path/

So what I'm trying to do is redirect any URL following the old URL format, including the root / to the new format. This process should strip all URI parameters in the URL and replace it with the corresponding path.

I reached out to the guys over at WPML and they don't know how to do it.

I've tried two different ways:

```
location = / {
   if ($args ~ "^lang=(fr)") {
        set $key1 $1;
        rewrite ^.*$  /fr last;
        }
}
```

As well as:

```
rewrite ^/.*\?lang\=fr$ /index.php? permanent;
```

But unfortunately from what I can tell, neither of these seem to do anything. I'm really familiar with regex but for some reason I'm having a hard time with these nginx rewrites.

I was surprised that there are very few examples in the nginx docs and on google about rewriting URL parameters. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `if ($arg_lang) { return 301 /$arg_lang$uri; }`

Comment: Wow, this actually seems to do the trick, thanks! What I've been missing that $arg_xxxx obviously has special meaning to nginx.